# Update Site for Earlier Version of Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring-tool-suite

My company's legal department has approved the use of Spring Tool Suite 3.6.3 for Eclipse 4.3. I noticed the eclipse update site for Eclipse 4.3 currently just has Spring Tool Suite 3.6.4. Is there a URL where the earlier Spring Tool Suite 3.6.3 version for Eclipse 4.3 can be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. The update site for STS 3.6.3 on Eclipse 4.3 is:
http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.6.3.RELEASE/e4.3

The distribution builds of STS 3.6.3 are here:

Windows (32bit): http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3/dist/e4.3/spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.3.2-win32.zip

Windows (64bit): http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3/dist/e4.3/spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.3.2-win32-x86_64.zip

OSX (64bit): http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3/dist/e4.3/spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.3.2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz

Linux (32bit): http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3/dist/e4.3/spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.3.2-linux-gtk.tar.gz

Linux (64bit): http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3/dist/e4.3/spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.3.2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

I want able to locate the URL: http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.6.3.RELEASE/e4.3/springsource-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.3.2-updatesite.zip